# Should I create executor service for each request in spring controller?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to build a rest API controller which takes a list of hostnames as input and a command to be executed in each hostname

```
@RequestMapping("/tasks")
    public Result execute(@RequestParam(value="hostList") List<HostName> hosts, String command) {
        //1. Execute the command in each hostname asynchronously and get completable future.
        //2. Get a list of completable future for each hostname command execution
        //3. Wait for them to complete and then compose the result
    }
```

The question is that, step 1 needs to happen asynchronously for each hostname.
I am planning to create a an executor service (with thread pool size of hosts.size()) **for each request** and then execute step 1 in that thread pool.

But I think it is a bad idea to create executor for each request, since that will consume a lot of memory.

Is this correct way forward or is there something in built in spring to take care of this scenario.

Please note that the list of hosts can vary from 1 to 20

Comment: Is there a reason why you should not be able to reuse 1 `ExecutorService`? With each new instance you are allocating new threads, which are rather expensive. Additionally creating more threads than your CPU can handle gives you no advantage whatsoever.

Comment: @ŠimonKocúrek For I/O-driven workloads (where you cannot use non-blocking IO), it does make sense to have more threads than CPU core. But I agree that a single, application-wide executor appears better, if only to be able to control the total resource limit.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no reason to create a new executor for each request. You should have one executor and when your request comes your code should create a number of runnable tasks and submit them to the executor. Also in your case, since you are talking about running some command on different hosts, it means that you don't run any command on your server. You somehow send a message to the relevant host with command to execute. (I assume through a queue). So your commands can NOT be executed synchronously even if you wanted to, since each command is executed on a different host. So, obviously they can not be running in the same process, let alone the same thread. So in your case, you probably don't need to have any Executor at all.

Comment: I agree with your answer that he should not create a new executor/Thread for each request, however, I do not agree with your comment about not being able to execute the commands synchronously. You will still be able to execute the commands synchronously through some sort of third system that keeps state of the arrived commands for each host, and to then execute the commands once this barrier was reached. Next to this, you can use a executor as you maybe want to just fire away your request and let the Executor/Thread pool execute your task and the client to continue instead of wait (NIO appr.)

Comment: @ Remco Buddelmeijer - I suppose it is a bit of a moot point, but I guess you are right. He can run all tasks and then return the answer which would be synch execution. But still, there is an async component to it, since he has to communicate with different host(s)

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to be making a new Thread for each request. You can either have a thread pool with fixed size N created by an Executor or submit your tasks on the Tomcat/any other provider threads that are used to fulfil your HTTP request. I gave two solutions below that may apply to one of your use cases

**Below Solution is for when you want the client to wait for their commands to be submitted to their host**

You should send a message to your hosts to execute the commands (maybe through a REST API or anything else), and wait for these tasks to either be executed or to be submitted: this all depends on your use case.

**Below Solution is for when you want to be able to queue your commands**

You can submit tasks to the created Thread Pool which will execute your tasks in an FI-FO order.
Depending on your use case, you can either use 1 or multiple (not too many Threads as this may only degrade your overall performance) threads in your Thread Pool. These tasks will then be executed when picked from the queue.